# Pantheon-files can't connect to samba server with min protocol SMB2 or SMB3

Tags: pantheon-files, samba

Because the SMB1 protocol is outdated, I would like to use the SMB2 or SMB3 protocol to connect from my elementaryos laptop to a samba share on my ubuntu machine. But when I configure min protocol SMB2 the filemanager in elementaryos fails to connect to the server although smbclient works fine on elementaryos.

Is SMB2 or SMB3 supported by pantheon-files and if not, when will it be supported?

Answer (score 0):

Is this any help?
https://askubuntu.com/questions/919967/how-to-tell-gigolo-gvfs-to-use-smbv2-for-windows-shares

Like Thunar, Files relies on gvfs and does not get involved with the technicalities of the connection.  Maybe a later version of gvfs (which will be used with  the next release) will improve the situation.